# Can't change text after async task

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am developing android application. It connects to the internet using async task and gets JSON result. After that it saves values to private String variables. This task works with button listener in fragment class. After button click, async task executes. Next command is setText to TextView. Async task works well, but nothing appears. If I start preference activity and then come back, it is there. So it works but it doesn't appear. Maybe I have to "repaint" screen but I don't know how. Or some other ideas? Please help.

I created basic android project in Eclipse/Android studio where I have MainActivity class and PlaceholderFragment class is extending Fragment (with no Fragment tag in XML - activity_main.xml is FrameLayout and fragment_main.xml is Linear Layout). Firstly class PlaceholderFragment was inner static class but I putted it out to separate .java file. Look at my code, I tried to simplify it:

MainActivity.java

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// URL to get JSON
private static String pref_url;
private static String pref_key;
private static String pref_check;

private String status = " ";

private static final String PARAM_KEY = "key";
private static final String PARAM_CODE = "code";
private static final String PARAM_CHECK = "check";

// JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public void btnDoIt() {
    new JSONParse().execute();
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public String createUrl() {
    String url = pref_url + "?" + PARAM_KEY + "=" + pref_key + "&"
            + PARAM_CODE + "=" + Code + "&" + PARAM_CHECK + "="
            + pref_check;
    return url;
}

 private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Getting JSON from URL

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(createUrl());

        return json;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Storing JSON item in a Variable
            String vypis_key = json.getString(TAG_KEY);
            status = json.getString(TAG_STATUS);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "//KEY = " + vypis_key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();   //it writes KEY = OK 

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PlaceholderFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

View rootView;
Button btngetdata;


public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    btngetdata = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnUplatni);
    btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).btnDoIt();
            setTextInTextView(getString(R.string.text_status) + " " + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getStatus(), R.id.textstatus);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    setTextInTextView(getString(R.string.text_status) + " " + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getStatus(), R.id.textstatus);
}

public void setTextInTextView(String text, int id) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(id);
    textView.setText(text);
}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.zonemedia.skener.PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textstatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_status" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUplatni"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_Uplatni" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.zonemedia.skener.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you do the following actions in the onclick()

```
       ((MainActivity) getActivity()).btnDoIt();
        setTextInTextView(getString(R.string.text_status) + " " + ((MainActivity)         getActivity()).getStatus(), R.id.textstatus);
```

when the second instruction is being executed the first one (the async task) is still being executed.

I would advise you to create a callback with the status in the activity and call it in the onPostExecute of the asynctask, than, in this callback, change the textview.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating status in  `onPostExecute` method of AsyncTask.And getting status after calling AsyncTask,so it do not update status text.

So update status text  in `onPostExecute` execute method of `AsyncTask`.i.e.

Simply change

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).btnDoIt();
        setTextInTextView(getString(R.string.text_status) + " " + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getStatus(), R.id.textstatus);
```

to

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).btnDoIt();
```

And rewrite your `onPostExecute` method as

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Storing JSON item in a Variable
            String vypis_key = json.getString(TAG_KEY);
            status = json.getString(TAG_STATUS);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "//KEY = " + vypis_key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();   //it writes KEY = OK 

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = (PlaceholderFragmen)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main);
            fragment.setTextInTextView(getString(R.string.text_status) + " " + getStatus());
} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Initialize textview in `OncreateView` method  of fragment and declare as `TextView textView;` in Fragment class as

```
 TextView textView;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textstatus);
    //rest code
```

And Rewrite `setTextInTextViewmethod` as

```
public void setTextInTextView(String text) {
    textView.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about it, but look at my xml layout files. I don't have fragment tag there. I think that I can find view by id, not fragment. What I should change / Where I should add fragment id?

Comment: @Brano_SR there is no tag as "fragment",fragment_main is your fragment,get this as I suggested.

Comment: I added `android:id="@+id/fragment_main"` to LinearLayout in fragment_main.xml. I can find fragment by id but I have error: `fragment.setTextInTextView(getString(R.string.text_status) + " " + getStatus(), R.id.textstatus);` with reason: The method setTextInTextView(String,int) in undefined for the type Fragment.

Comment: I tried. Result is error: NullPointerException in PlaceholderFragment class, setTextInTextView method: ` TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(id); `

Comment: NullPointerException again on line `fragment.setTextInTextView(getString(R.string.text_status) + " " + getStatus(), R.id.textstatus)`

Comment: unfortunately result is still the same. NullPointerException on line fragment.setTextIn....

Answer (score 0):

Your getStatus() method returns the value that you set it to which is " ".

Try updating you onPostExecute method to set the value of status to that of the "vypis_key" variable. This will work but only when the AsyncTask has finished so you will need to come up with a way to ensure that has happened before you update your TextView.